# Google App Engine with Golang: How do you parse URL path segments as variables?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, url-routing

In Google App Engine with Go, I would like to take a URL like this:

```
http://www.example.com/api/account/123456/product/573832
```

and treat it like this:

```
http://www.example.com/api/account/{acctId}/product/{prodId}
```

Then access `acctId` and `prodId` in my handler function.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 8):

There you are:

```
func httpHandle(httpResponse http.ResponseWriter, httpRequest *http.Request) {
    urlPart := strings.Split(httpRequest.URL.Path, "/")
    // urlPart[3] is the acctId, urlPart[5] is the prodId
}
```

Answer (score 1):

httprouter seems to be fast and simplistic. If you need a more advanced sophisticated routing framework then look elsewhere?

```
go get github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter
```

then:

```
package goseo

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

func init() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/", index)
    http.Handle("/", router)
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, world!")
}
```

example matches:

```
Pattern: /user/:user

 /user/gordon              match
 /user/you                 match
 /user/gordon/profile      no match
 /user/                    no match
```

further examples:

https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter

Further, I have an app.yaml:

```
application: student-course-review
module: goseo
version: goseo1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /static/(.+)
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*)

- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

Comment: Try go's strings package.  The question is about splitting a string.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to consider using a library, like "httprouter" for this. This [guide](http://nicolasmerouze.com/guide-routers-golang/) might help you choose one.

Comment: Including an example bit of code in your answer may help the OP to better understand your answer. “link only” answers are most often not the best possible answer.

Comment: You might want to consider not replying to a simple question about splitting a string by recommending a third-party library.